# Dealing with large data sets from CosmosDB in Spark

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb

I learned how to create `DataFrame` with data coming from `CosmosDB` using spark-cosmosdb connector, so now I would like to do something with the DataFrame. Everything is fine until I am operating on small collections of data(or I add additional `custom_query` in read configuration to narrow the data scope).

For example, I am able to create a DF, and then do `df.show()` or create a temp view on top of it and then do `%%sql select * from c`. But when I try to do `df.count()` or `%%sql select * from c order by name desc` then I receive error saying: `Request rate is large` ([Full stacktrace on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/E5mAG54y)). I thought about materializing the table into hive (`df.write.saveAsTable(tableName)`) I got the very same error.

Is there a way to somehow reduce the amount of request that will go to the database when calling such heavy functions? Or another way to materialize the data in hive so I can work on it later, without need to go through connector again and again? This limitation looks really like a pain in the neck, so I cannot do anything with the data.

The troughput of the collection is 400 RU/s. Parameters of HdInsinght: Spark 2.2 on Linux (HDI 3.6), Scala: 2.11.8. I am using JupyterNotebook with PySpark 3 Kernel. Here is whole code I am using:

```
%%configure -f
{ "name":"Spark-to-Cosmos_DB_Connector", 
  "jars": ["wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11-1.1.0.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/azure-documentdb-1.14.0.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/azure-documentdb-rx-0.9.0-rc2.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/json-20140107.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/rxjava-1.3.0.jar", "wasb:///example/jars/1.0.0/rxnetty-0.4.20.jar"],
  "conf": {
        "spark.jars.packages": "com.microsoft.azure:azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.2.0_2.11:1.1.0",
        "spark.jars.excludes": "org.scala-lang:scala-reflect"
   }
}

iotConfig = {
    "Endpoint" : "https://myDB.documents.azure.com:443/",
    "Masterkey" : "myKey==",
    "Database" : "test",
    "preferredRegions" : "West Europe",
    "Collection" : "surrogate",
    "SamplingRation" : "1.0",
    "schema_samplesize" : "1000",
    "query_pagesize" : "2147483647"
}

df = spark.read.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").options(**iotConfig).load()

df.createOrReplaceTempView("c")

#will work
df.show()

#wont work
%%sql
select count(*) from c

#wont work
%%sql
select * from c order by name desc

#wont work    
df.count()

#wont work    
df.write.saveAsTable('table')
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that at 400 RUs, Spark will be requesting too much data too quickly from the collection when using `azure-cosmosdb-spark`.  A potential approach would be to use `pydocumentdb` where the request will not be from the Spark executors (like when using `azure-cosmosdb-spark`) but from the driver.  This would potentially slow down the request rate.

When using `azure-cosmosdb-spark`, you can reduce the request rate by decreasing the size of the `query_pagesize`.  Here's the current work-in-progress of the [configuration reference guide](https://github.com/dennyglee/azure-cosmosdb-spark/blob/master/docs/configuration-reference-guide.md).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try increasing the throughput on your collection. That is exactly what the `Request rate is large` error indicates

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for your reply. This was my first thought, but before I change my DTU, I'd first like to know if there is any way to limit the number of requests send at one time (so processing would last longer, but would be finished).

Answer (score 0):

we had a similar issue where we were pulling data from `cosmosdb` collection (1000 R/U, ~25GB, ~15 Million documents) via `azure-cosmosdb-spark` connector.

For smooth batch pull use `query_pagesize = <XXXX>` in config where XXXX should be relatively small (like ~ 100K.). this will ensure the limited load on the collection and thus smooth response.

For querying in `DataFrame` loaded and getting count we used the following code. (scala)

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("c") 

var records = spark.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM c") 

records.show()`
```